# Properties of $d(x,y) = \vert x_1 - y_1\vert^\frac{1}{2} + \vert x_2-y_2\vert^\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Given $x=(x_1,x_2),y=(y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, let $$d(x,y) = \vert x_1 - y_1\vert^\frac{1}{2} + \vert x_2-y_2\vert^\frac{1}{2}.$$

This is a distance on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but is it translation invariant? And are the open balls $B_r(x) = \{y: d(y,x)< r\}$ convex sets?

Answer (score 0):

Translation invariance is easy to see/check. The ball is not convex, try $B_1(0)$ and $x=(1,0)$, $y=(0,1)$ and the convex combination $(1/2,1/2)$. (Edit: you may have to increase the radius a little because otherwise the ball doesn't contain $x,y$. But its just a technical detail..)